# How to adjust Table Tr and Td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

Here, I M using [jQuery Datatable](https://datatables.net/) plugin, but my image `td` is taking too much width while the action-buttons `td` is allocated less width.

As a result each button is overlapping the other.

How can I assign the width, in Bootstrap, CSS and jQuery according their data storing width?

**Image** for clear understanding
[image]

Here is the whole code in **View**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#book-table').DataTable();
     });
   </script>

    <div class="container">
    <?=anchor('','<i class="ion-arrow-return-left"> </i>Go Back',
      ['class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm','onclick'=>'window.history.back()' 
      ,'style'=>'margin:2%;'])?>
          <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-10">

    <table id="book-table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="2" 
  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>     
 <tr>                   
  <th>Image</th>
 <th>Order No</th>
 <th>Product</th>
 <th>Ordered Date</th>
 <th>Innvoice</th>
 <th>Action</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
   <?php  foreach($new_orders as $ordr) {?>

  <tr>
    <td>
    <?phpif(!is_null($ordr['image'])){
     ?>
    <img src="<?=$ordr['image']?>" class=img-thumbnail alt='Cinque Terre' 
    style="width: 20%; height: 20%">
   <?}?>
    </td>
    <td><?=$ordr['s_order_id']?></td>
    <td><?=$ordr['name']?></td>
    <td><?=$ordr['s_order_date']?></td>
    <td><?=$ordr['innvoice']?></td>
    <td>

     <?php echoanchor('vendors/pages/selected_order_detail_page/'
      .$ordr['s_order_id'].'/'.$ordr['id'],'<i class="fa fa-circle-o">
       </i> Detail',['class'=>'btn btn-success btn-xs'])?>

      <?php echo anchor('vendors/addcontroller/accept_order/'
       .$ordr['s_order_id'].'/'.$ordr['id'],
      '<i class="ion-checkmark-circled"></i> Accept',
        ['class'=>'btn btn-info btn-xs','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you 
         Serious to accept the order?')"])?>

       <?php echo anchor('vendors/deletecontroller/rejected_order/'
       .$ordr['s_order_id'].'/'.$ordr['id'],
        '<i class="ion-trash-b"></i> Reject',['class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-
           xs','onclick'=>"return 
          confirm('Think, Before Rejecting the order?')"])?>
       </td>       

    </tr>  
    <?php }?>
      </tbody>
   </table> 
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: In coding context, a clear understanding is in most cases not conveyed by an image, but by code.

Comment: in your columns definition, you can st the widths.

Comment: I typically set the width of all but one column then put the table in a div with a max-width set

Comment: Here is the right page for you in [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width).

Comment: thanks Louys it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this worked, changing the image **Td** width.. [find in detail Datatable document](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#book-table').dataTable( {
   "columnDefs": [
     { "width": "15%", "targets": 0 }]
     } );
 </script>
```